# Google Task Queues JSON API Transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-java-client

Is it possible to put a record to Google Cloud Datastore and a task to the TaskQueue atomically outside of App Engine using their REST APIs?

Basically achieve [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/#Java_Tasks_within_transactions) (below) but in Container Engine and without using the high-level App Engine-specific APIs.

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
try {
    Transaction txn = ds.beginTransaction();

    // ...

    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/path/to/my/worker"));

    // ...
    txn.commit();
} catch (DatastoreFailureException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible using the Cloud Datastore API.